# Custom Auth Provider Setup - State Parameter is not accessible for change

Tags: community, authentication, auth-provider, open-id-connect, azure

I have an open id integration done between salesforce and azure B2C. I have setup the auth provider with all information. When I am trying to login in or authenticate from my community it redirects to azure login page and after giving username password it redirects to community home page which is as expected.
Now I have another page on community site which is after login to community user can go to that page and it has an LWC component with just a button to click. On click of this button I have to re-authenticate the same user again for MFA. Azure has its own MFA we are triggering that by passing addition parameter in URL which is "mfa_require=1".
So on click of that button it successfully redirect to mfa page but when i give the authentication code it fails and display the error "State is not valid".

Now when user login very first time the state parameter gets auto generated by salesforce. I do not know how. And in 2nd time during MFA process I am generating a random string as state parameter which is not recognising by salesforce when callback happens.

I am looking for help on understanding how the state parameter gets generated? How can I store it temporarily for my mfa functionality?